# How to solve Nexmo server error code 504?

Tags: vonage

I send SMS and get callback with the error

```
 { message: 'Server Error',
statusCode: 504,
headers: 
 { server: 'nginx',
   date: 'Tue, 11 Sep 2018 14:33:10 GMT',
   'content-type': 'text/html',
   'content-length': '176',
   connection: 'close',
   'x-frame-options': 'deny',
   'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block;',
   'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains',
   'content-disposition': 'attachment; filename="api.txt"',
   'x-nexmo-trace-id': '0ad2e1a2a9246b2de9d2802f86ba0fe5' } }
```

I don't know what does it mean. Please, help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was an issue with the Nexmo API on 11 September 2018 that caused this problem. See https://www.nexmostatus.com/incidents/qdl3bhsq1cbz